# save all random forest decision trees in a same pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, save, random-forest, decision-tree

I’ ve tried to save every decision tree of a Random Forest in just One pdf file, however, I only have got save the last decision tree… Anybody knows how I could save every tree?

I would appreciate a Python code that could help me.

Thank you very much!

Regards

Comment: Maybe add some context to your question, a bit a code or python package you are using. You could check [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) for some examples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.